# Ext JS Combo. Keep expanded while filtering

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, combobox, extjs6-classic

I have a 2 field combo with the local store being mannualy loaded from outside.
I want this combo to be in the expanded state when I type in and filter.

I have setup the listeners with the filter. The filter works fine.

```
 this.listeners = {
        beforequery: function(queryPlan){
            me.store.clearFilter(true);
            me.store.filter(filter);
            return true;
        }
    };
```

The thing is that when I start typing in the combo, sometimes it opens after entering the first letter and then collapses even if there are filtered values to be shown. I have to press down key to see the filtered list.

But if I delete characters by the backspace key - It keeps being open - Actually this is what I need.

I understand that there is some trick with event chain, but cannot get exactly how. 
Manual calling combo.expand() has no effect.
Makes no sense if I have typeAhead=true or I do not.
Probably this is because I use displayTpl instead of displayField.

Any Ideas ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is my solution.
I do it in BeforeExpand Event. In that event I can filter store.
But the problem is it can not expand after filter...
If I want filter, I need to clear value of that combo

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is best solution, but you can `getPicker()` of your `combo` and add show / hide related event handler to it with your hide / show custom logic within it (`beforehide` for example or any other that fits your logic).

```
combo.getPicker().on(
    'beforehide',
    function() {
        // Your hide logic here
    }
);
```

*Combo picker component is [`Ext.view.Boundlist`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundList), so in your controller something like this should work aswell:*

```
init: function () {
    this.control({
        'combo[name=myCombo] boundlist': {
            beforehide: this.myHandler
        }
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1at8)